# MakeFiles and dependencies

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile and I can't figure out how to include all my source files without having to write all source file I want to use. Here is the makefile I'm currently  using:

```
GCC = $(GNUARM_HOME)\bin\arm-elf-gcc.exe
SOURCES=ShapeApp.cpp Square.cpp Circle.cpp Shape.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
#$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(GCC) -c $< -o $@
```

How do I automatically add new source file without having to add it to the sources line?

Comment: Outside of toy projects, you do not want to do this very often.  You get into trouble the first time you make a backup copy of a file, or leave a bit of test code lying around.  Not listing exactly the modules that make up the program is a recipe for trouble.  If each file was a complete self-contained program, which is what Dirk suggested, it is more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have used in an `examples/` directory where each file is mapped one-to-one to an executable:

```
sources :=   $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs :=  $(sources:.cpp=)

[ more settings about compiler flags, linker options, ...]


all :        $(programs)
```

That can be enough as `make` knows how to turn a .cpp file into an object file and then into an executable.  Note that this is on Linux so for Windoze you'd probably need to do

```
programs :=     $(sources:.cpp=.exe)
```

to append the .exe.

Comment: The OP only wants one executable. (Although he can probably figure out the rest from your answer)

Comment: Correct. All he needs is the sources statement.